# Sending mail through SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I am trying to setup my program to sent e-mails through smtp server which is not my localhost. I am using `System.Net.Mail`. Like this:

```
var mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
var mMailMessage = new MailMessage()
{
 Subject = subject,
 Body = body,
 IsBodyHtml = true,
 Priority = MailPriority.Normal,
};
```

The case is that it is perfectly working when I using google smtp server `smtp.gmail.com`. But  I treed to send e-mails using another server to different accounts. And for example hotmail.com received it (though was moved to junk) but gmail.com not.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct port number?

Comment: Yes I am. As recomended by server provider 587. For `smtp.gmail.com` It's working ok. For another prowider delivers to `hotmail.com` account but not to `gmail.com` account.

Comment: What other SMTP servers did you use?

Comment: It's just our local company which host some servers and provides other related services.

Comment: if you need to send more email to users then i suggest mailchimp like plugins

Comment: FYI, it's not a C# SmtpClient. It's a .NET SmtpClient.

Comment: @John Saunders Thanks. But I never insisted on that I think. Nor that I asked this.

Comment: That was in your title

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok then. Accepted. Probably I meant that I am not interested in VB.

Comment: Ok. FYI that sort of "metadata" does not belong in a title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders interesting. By the way most of todays questions have this 'useless' metadata (like 'mySql','Android','jQuery' etc) and needs to be amended then I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here comes the hint. Never use ip of pc. Replace it with domain name or localhost. This did the trick for me. As bonus `AlternateViews` can also help.